# Dual space (Wikipedia)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I am struggling to understand something [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space):

''If $V$ consists of the space of geometrical vectors (arrows) in the plane, then the level curves of an element of $V^*$ form a family of parallel lines in $V$. So an element of $V^*$ can be intuitively thought of as a particular family of parallel lines covering the plane. To compute the value of a functional on a given vector, one needs only to determine which of the lines the vector lies on. Or, informally, one "counts" how many lines the vector crosses.''

$V$ is a finite dimensional real vector space. Say, $V=\mathbb R^3$. I have several problems with this text: One is that I don't know what a geometrical vector or arrow is. Is it just a vector?

The next thing I don't understand is what they mean by level curves of an element of $V^\ast$. I mean, $f \in V^\ast$ maps into $\mathbb R$. Does level then mean constant? If $f$ was a map into $\mathbb R^3$ then I understand that level curve would mean the intersection of $f$ with a plane parallel to the $xy$ plane. But what does it mean if the range is only one dimensional?

Please could someone help me understand what the paragraph above means?

Comment: I have to agree that this is a pretty bad explanation. Doesn't help my intuition at all either. Honestly it's easiest to just learn about dual spaces by looking at them rigorously as the space of linear maps from a space to the field it's over.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a free translation: "An element of the dual space $(\mathbf{R}^{2})^{*}$ of the plane $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ has the form $f(x, y) = ax + by$ for some real numbers $a$, $b$. If $c$ is real, the *level curve* at height $c$ is the solution set of $ax + by = c$, namely the line $\ell$ orthogonal to $(a, b)$ and lying at distance $c/\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$ from the origin along $(a, b)$. If $v$ is a vector (arrow) based at $(0, 0)$ whose head lies on $\ell$, then $f(v) = c$."

Answer (score 0):

By "the space of geometric vectors in the plane" the author just means $V = \mathbb R^2$.

The level sets of a map $f : V \to \mathbb R$ are the sets $\{x \in V : f(x) = c\}$ for constants $c$. In the case of a linear $f$, the level sets are parallel hyperplanes (lines when $V = \mathbb R^2$).